# Linux change pgrp (process group) during c program execution

Tags: c, linux, process, grep

C Linux change pgrp  (process group) during program execution

Is there a piece of working C code to change your own process group during program execution.
Maybe someone can make the testprogram work below.

Bash verification:

```
# ps -opid,pgrp,cmd | grep <pid>
```

C test program:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  pid_t mypid = getpid();
  printf ("issue: ps -opid,pgrp,cmd | grep %d\n", (int) mypid);

  printf ("will change my pgrp in 10 sec\n");
  sleep  (10);

  // missing here is the "magic" statment to change current process group

  printf ("issue: ps -opid,pgrp,cmd | grep %d\n", (int) pid);

  sleep (1000);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From man pages of setsid.

http://linux.die.net/man/2/setsid

**setsid() creates a new session if the calling process is not a process group leader. The calling process is the leader of the new session, the process group leader of the new process group, and has no controlling terminal.**

or you can changed your process's group by setpgid() system call. For man's pages of setpgid 
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setpgid.2.html

**setpgid() sets the PGID of the process specified by pid to pgid.  If pid is zero, then the process ID of the calling process is used. If pgid is zero, then the PGID of the process specified by pid is made        the same as its process ID.**

but it is mandatory that both process groups belong to the same session i.e. the group from you moving from and the group you moving to. Here is an example of a code which changes process group  with out using setsid() and fork() :

```
int main()
{
  pid_t ppgid = 0;
  pid_t mypid = getpid();
  pid_t ppid  = getppid();
  printf("My pid is %d and my pgid is %d\n", getpid(), getpgid(mypid));
  ppgid = getpgid(ppid);
  printf("My parent's pid is %d and his pgid is %d\n", ppid, ppgid);  

  setpgid(mypid, ppgid);  

  printf("Now my pgid is changed to my parent's pgid(%d)\n", getpgid(mypid));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: try the test programm and you will see it will not work

Comment: Thats probably because you process is already a group leader. I dont know if this solves your problem but you can change your process group id by forking your process, let the parent die and call setsid in your child process. This way your child process wont be group leader and will change its group id.

Comment: Yes this is the way to daemonize a process for example, that works I tested it. I am curious if I can change an existing process without forking...

Comment: Last thing, so I can only set an already existing pgrp (with same session id). It is impossible to assign a new pgrp, correct ?

Comment: Just tested successfully if I am not the session leader I can assign my pid as pgid, using setpgrp() or setpgid(0,0). Thanks a lot that you made me understand.